# Setting up git on the Centos Linux server

Tags: git, github, git-svn

[image]I am new to git. I have installed git on the server and set up the repository there. But I am facing problem in cloning that repository on my local windows machine.
On my windows machine I am using Tortoise Git for cloning.
Could anyone help what url I need to provide to clone that repository on my local machine ? 
Below is the message I am getting

**git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (25381 ms @ 21-03-2014 14:51:54),**
Attached is the screenshot for the same ...

Comment: in git u have ssl and http link, i think you need to use the http link when you clone the repo

Comment: But how can i use that . Could you provide me any reference ?

Comment: I've uplaode this image http://prntscr.com/32qjsn so you have a graphical explain please let me know if this helped

Answer (score 0):

First, check the remote URL used: HTTPS or SSH.

If it is SSH:

- check that the `ssh user@CentOSserver` gives you a prompt
- check that `ssh user@CentOSserve /path_to_repository` is accessible (readable)